# How can I access a Django returned json object in javascript / on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm having hard times to find a way to use my Django returned data on the clientside. I think I mix up several concepts here.

This is my view that calls the model `StocksPrice` and returns all data in the table column `stockName`:

```
def getStocksAvailable(request, *args, **kwargs):
    StocksAvailable = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values(stockName))
    return HttpResponse({"data": StocksAvailable})
```

and according Javascript part for testing purposes:

```
var received_data = "{{ StocksAvailable }}"
    console.log(received_data);

# Outputs: {{ StocksAvailable }}
```

I also tried it using `render` in the view:

```
def getStocksAvailable(request, *args, **kwargs):
    StocksAvailable = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values(stockName))
    return render({"data": StocksAvailable})
```

Why does JS logs it as a string whereas it is supposed to be a variable containing the returned json object? And how could I basically print the returned data from the view for debugging (maybe s.th. is wrong with the json itself)?

### Updated Version @Willems response

Url mapping:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('terminal/getStocksAvailable/', get_stocks_available),
]
```

View

```
def get_stocks_available(request, *args, **kwargs):
    stocks_available = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values(stockName))
    return JsonResponse({'data': json.loads(stocks_available)})
```

Model

```
class StocksPrice(models.Model):
    stockName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
     [...]

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'StocksPrice'
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('getStocksAvailable/', {
        method: 'GET',
        async: "True",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            var received_data = "{{stocks_available}}"
            console.log(received_data);
        }
    })
});
```

which now throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\CFD\CFD\terminal\views.py", line 10, in get_stocks_available
    stocks_available = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values(stockName))
NameError: name 'stockName' is not defined
[17/May/2020 14:36:56] "GET /terminal/getStocksAvailable/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16181
[17/May/2020 14:36:56] "GET /terminal/getStocksAvailable/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16181
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does JS logs it as a string whereas it is supposed to be a variable containing the returned json object?

Because `serializers.serialize(..)` **returns a string**. If you want to wrap it in an object, you can for example decode it:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_stocks_available(request, *args, **kwargs):
    stocks_available = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values(stockName))
    return JsonResponse({'data': json.loads(stocks_available)})
```

**EDIT1:**

You furthermore need to pass a value for `stockName`, and process the `result.view_data` (this is a parameter in the data):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('getStocksAvailable/?stockName=???', {
        method: 'GET',
        async: "True",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var received_data = result.view_data;
            console.log(received_data);
        }
    })
});
```

with `???` to fill in.

in the view, you can then access `request.GET` to obtain the value for `stockName`:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_stocks_available(request, *args, **kwargs):
    stockName = request.GET['stockName']
    stocks_available = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values(stockName))
    return JsonResponse({'data': json.loads(stocks_available)})
```

**EDIT2:**

If you want to use values from a *column* named `stockName`, then you should use:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_stocks_available(request, *args, **kwars):
    stocks_available = serializers.serialize('json', StocksPrice.objects.values('stockName'))
    return JsonResponse({'data': json.loads(stocks_available)})
```

and at the JavaScript side:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('getStocksAvailable/', {
        method: 'GET',
        async: "True",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var received_data = result.view_data;
            console.log(received_data);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt support. I replaced it with your view, but the clientside still does not log the data. I guess I am still missing s.th. here :/

Comment: @Phanti: how exactly do you *fetch* the data? With an AJAX request?

Comment: What I mean is: `getStocksAvailable` returns a Json blob, you have some JavaScript I assume that triggers this view, and process the data?

Comment: sorry for the missing input. I have an AJAX call upon document.ready

Comment: Ah, but you did not define a value for `stockName`., see edit.

Comment: I'd actually like to get all available stockNames from the model which are stored in the field/column `stockName` as one json to populate a search field on the clientside :/ Not sure If my database query is correct since it suggests "name stockName is not defined" ?

Comment: @Phanti: in that case you should pass a string `'stockName'`.

Comment: I highly appreciate your support. I forgot to import json into the views file... ("I had one job") Everything works now! Thank youj so much, best wishes to Belgium!